Newton-Raphson Principle
In the following picture, there are typo in notations. The Y-axis will be $t(x)$, and on the X-axis, the first point is $x^m$ and the 2nd point is $x^{(m-1)}.$
My question is I didn't understand the graph. Can anyone please explain why is the point $x^m$ inside the curve, and which point on X-axis is  $x^{(m-1)}$? Is it always be the case that $x^{(m-1)}$ will be outside the curve? How does $x^{m}$ become root $(\bullet)$?


